# functions not defined in js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a website. I'm having a lot of errors with javascript. The majority are functions not defined. eg: $.

There are other functions that share the same problem.

I don't fully understand how to resolve this issue and would love somebody to review my code as this would help me better understand my problem.

I've kept my script src link at the top of the links in the body, which I understood to be the cause. However, it appears that it is not the cause.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('.js--section-features').waypoint(function (direction) {
        if (direction == "down") {
            $('nav').addClass('sticky');
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
        }
    }, {
        offset: '90px;'
    });






    /*This is to offset sticky nav as to not overlap touch section*/
    var shiftWindow = function () {
        scrollBy(0, -75);
    };
    if (location.hash) shiftWindow();
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", shiftWindow);

    /*maps*/

    var map = new GMaps({
        div: '.map',
        lat: 52.760514,
        lng: -1.6500,
        zoom: 12
    });
    52.7610273, -1.7181805;

    map.addMarker({
        lat: 52.7604902,
        lng: -1.7172825,
        title: 'lw swim school',
        infoWindow: {
            content: '<p>LW swim school</p>'
        }
    });





    /*mobile nav*/

    $('.js--nav-icon').click(function () {
        var nav = $('.js--main-nav');
        var icon = $('.js--nav-icon ion-icon');

        nav.slideToggle(200);
        if (icon.hasClass('ios-menu-cross')) {
            icon.addClass('ios-close');
            icon.removeClass('ios-menu-cross');
        } else {
            icon.addClass('ios-menu-cross');
            icon.removeClass('ios-close');
        }
    });
});
```

Here are my script src links in my html at the bottom of the body in this order

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/selectivizr/1.0.3b/selectivizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/gmaps.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.4.8/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
```

$, .windows, scollby, location, GMaps are all not defined. I hope someone can advise me, thank you in advance.

Comment: If you don't import jQuery *before* your code that wants to use it that will definitely mean that `$` will be undefined.

Comment: hi could you explain in a bit more detail please, if possible.

Comment: Scripts are processed in order (setting aside `async` and `deferred` scripts, of which your code has none).  If you have an inline script at the top of the page that references `$`, and the `<script>` tag that imports jQuery comes after that in the document, then things won't work. Your code will have to come after the import of jQuery, either by moving it to the end of the document or by moving the other imports up.

Comment: Is the script you posted an inline script, or is it the contents of `resources/js/script.js`?

Comment: Thank you for the in depth answer pointy, i do somewhat understand that the scripts need changing but i if you could show me which order my scripts should be in i would grateful. I can only apologise for my lack of knowledge in js as im fairly new to the language.

Comment: move <scripts> **code** </scripts> after all the js scripts.

Comment: hi barmar, my resources/js/script.js is my js code file, is  this to what your refering to?

Comment: All the declarations of scripts need to go at the top of your html file, in the head (not the body). Also, you don't seem to import JQuery, only JQuery.waypoints. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Hello Charlie, I did manage to put my scripts in the head but no avail, I will post a link to my html code pen in its original state before I posted the question, if you would like to see.